# Realtion in Realm objects set to null

Tags: android, realm, retrofit2

In my Android project I'm using Realm as database and Retrofit 2 to all web requests. Actually, I have some problem with storing object with relation in Realm.

I've something like that:

```
class ObjectA {
  @PrimaryKey
  Integer id;
  String name;
  ObjectB details;
}

class ObjectB {
  @PrimaryKey
  Integer id;
  String shortName;
  String longName;
}
```

I'm fetching my data in this way:

```
Call<ObjectA> call = getApiService().getMyObject();
call.enqueue(new Callback<ObjectA>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<ObjectA> call, final Response<ObjectA> response) {
      // Check if response is OK and other stuff

      // Store object in Realm
      Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
          @Override
          public void execute(Realm realm) {
              realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(response.body());
          }
      });
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<ObjectA> call, Throwable t) {
    // TBD
  }
});
```

After that, I see in my Realm database both objects ( instances of ObjectA and ObjectB) stored in proper tables. The problem is, that instance of ObjectB has in *details* column set 0, so I don't have the relation of two objects.
Do you have any suggestions or hints how can I resolve this issue and properly store both objects with proper relation?

**Edit**

My JSON:

```
{
  "id": 666,
  "name": "Dummy Object",
  "details": {
    "id": 123,
    "shortName": "Short Dummy Name",
    "longName": "Long Dummy Name"
  }
}
```

Comment: Citing [my article](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149), *if you see code like `Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(...)` in your code, it's going to break sooner or later*. Also, write transactions on the UI thread are bad.

Comment: Also, what's your JSON?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce please see my edit.

Comment: Hmm... I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by "that instance of ObjectB has in details column set 0"?

Comment: @beeender in ObjectA table in the row with my parsed and store ObjectA object I have set 0 in column 'details' responsible for the relation between two objects (ObjectA and ObjectB).

Comment: @Grzegorz I still don't get it. Why do you need to set `0`? which field did you set it to `0`? Also, if you have problem that the details shows `null` in the debugger, maybe this is why. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging

Comment: @beeender this isn't debugger issue. I'm watching directly into Realm database on my device. Wired thing is that in execute method objectA has set details to "null" (((ObjectB) response.body()).getDetails() = {my.package.name.models.ObjectB} "null"), but after resolving this object in debugger I see all fields set correctly. It looks like Retroft doesn't map this relation.

Comment: I've found that ((ObjectB) response.body()).getDetails() = {my.package.name.models.ObjectB} "null" is vivisble as null beacuse in ObjectB I have     @Override
    public String toString() {
       return shortName;
    }  but shortName in this object is empty.

Comment: empty `shortName` is expected with the same reason in the link i commented before. Realm generated a proxy class, so for a `RealmObject` managed by Realm, the corresponding field won't be used anymore, instead, it is using generated getter method to get the value through underlying database.